# passport jwt verify callback not called

Tags: node.js, restful-authentication, passport.js

I'm using passport-jwt package for simple authentication and the token is generated by jsonwebtoken. 
But the problem is that verify callback is never called.

Here my passport.js code.

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var User = require('../app/models/user');
var config = require('../config/database'); 
var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = function(req) {
    var token = null;
    if (req && req.headers) {
        token = req.headers.authorization;
    }
    return token;
};
opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
console.log(opts);
module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload._doc._id}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
              return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                done(null, user);
            } else {
              done(null, false);
            }
        });

    }));
};
```

Hope to hear from you.

Thanks

Comment: router config is just regular like samples: router.route('/timeRecords')
   .post(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}),timeRecordController.postTimeRecords)
   .get(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}),timeRecordController.getTimeRecords);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you should add 'JWT '(JWT and a space ahead of the original jwt signed). Please check this tutorial http://blog.slatepeak.com/building-a-basic-restful-api-for-a-chat-system/
by Joshua for assistance.
By the way, make sure that if you need a 'where' inside your findOne or not.

Comment: Thanks. you saved me. as a matter of fact, I was stuck in it for several days. You solved my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: The usage is illustrated here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt#include-the-jwt-in-requests