# passport-jwt token verification strategy never called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

I want to use passport-jwt to create my own strategy. According to several tutorial, i tried the following :

```
// auth.js
const passport = require("passport");
const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
const _ = require("lodash");
const users = require("./users.js");
const cfg = require("./config.js");

const ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
const JwtStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

var params = {
    secretOrKey: cfg.jwtSecret,
    //ignoreExpiration: false,
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    //passReqToCallback: false,
    jsonWebTokenOptions: {
        maxAge: "3 days"
    }
};

module.exports = function () {
    var strategy = new JwtStrategy(params, function (payload, done) {
        console.log('payload received', payload);
        // Just check in array is user is on it
        var user = users[_.findIndex(users, { id: payload.id })];
        if (user) {
            return done(null, {
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                scope: user.scope
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Echec : redirection")
            return done(new Error("User not found"), null);
        }
    });

    passport.use(strategy);

    return {
        initialize: function () {
            return passport.initialize();
        },
        authenticate: function () {
            return passport.authenticate("jwt", cfg.jwtSession);
        }
    };
}

// index.js

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const auth = require("./auth.js")();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const users = require("./users.js");
const cfg = require("./config.js");
const moment = require("moment")
const _ = require("lodash");

moment.locale("fr-FR");

var port = process.env.PORT || settings.port || 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(auth.initialize());

app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.user && req.body.password) {

        var user = users[_.findIndex(users, { user: req.body.user })];
        if (user) {
            res.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt.sign({
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                exp: Math.round(moment.duration(moment().add(3, 'days').diff(moment())).asSeconds())
        }, cfg.jwtSecret))
            res.json({
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                type: "Success"
            });
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
})

app.get('/', auth.authenticate(), function (req, res) {
    res.render('trend', {});
})

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Login page")
})

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

I'm able to generate a JWT and to set it in header as a Bearer token, by calling "/authenticate". But now, i'm stuck for the token validation. When i call "/", i'm first not able to debug my function, because nothing appear, even not a console log (so it's like the authentication strategy is never called, none of my multiple console.log is outputted) and it return me "Unauthorized"

I found something that would answer me here : [passport jwt verify callback not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833470/passport-jwt-verify-callback-not-called)

So i tried by replacing bearer to jwt, and i successfully got the token in params.jwtFromRequest. But still stuck for the strategy. And unfortunatelly, the link in the linked question is dead...

Any suggestions ?